# Javascript function validator

Tags: javascript, validation

im trying to create a javascript classroom validator that checks if the user enters a valid classroom number.

Rules:
Must be 4 digits
Must be in the format of: 2 Capital Leters followed by 2 digits

What i have so far. this only checks for the length. im not sure how to go about doing the other validator.

```
function classRoom_validate(CLASS, max)
{
    var CLASS_len = CLASS.value.length;
    if (CLASS_len != max && CLASS.value.match()
{
    alert("Invalid classroom");
    CLASS.focus();
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? If yes, add the `homework` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a regular expression:

```
r = /[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d/

r.test('AA21')
true

r.test('blah')
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Regex like this:

```
/[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}/.test(code);
```

> /[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}/.test("AA12"); // true
>   /[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}/.test("Ab12"); // false
>   /[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}/.test("Abc2"); // false

etc